# how to fetch latest time of a file in S3 in java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to `S3`. I need to fetch a file from `S3`, update it, and store it back to `S3`, so I need to fetch the latest time of this file in an existing module; it would be good if the answer is in java.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i have to update a existing file in S3 so for that i need latest updation time of the file so that i dont have redundant entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets a list of objects in the bucket. This also prints out each object’s name, the file size, and last modified date.

```
ObjectListing objects = conn.listObjects(bucket.getName());
do {
    for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objects.getObjectSummaries()) {
            System.out.println(objectSummary.getKey() + "\t" +
                    ObjectSummary.getSize() + "\t" +
                    StringUtils.fromDate(objectSummary.getLastModified()));
    }
    objects = conn.listNextBatchOfObjects(objects);
} while (objects.isTruncated());
```

The output will look something like this:

```
myphoto1.jpg 251262  2011-08-08T21:35:48.000Z
myphoto2.jpg 262518  2011-08-08T21:38:01.000Z
```

Ref for s3 examples including above one( LISTING A BUCKET’S CONTENT) is at: http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/radosgw/s3/java/